# Passing blocks around in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my app I there are various actions a user can perform only when logged in.

For instance, 'like'ing a picture.

When a user, who has not logged in, tries to perform these actions, I want a login screen to be presented, and if the login is successful, then perform the action immediately. (If they are already logged in, then the action would be performed right away.)

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
// in view controller, user taps like
block variable likeBlock = { likePicture(id) }
if loggedin 
    perform likeBlock
else
    appDelegate.attemptLoginWithViewController(thisViewController)
    andSuccess(likeBlock) andFailure(showError)
endif

func likePicture(id:int) {

}


// in appDelegate
attemptLoginWithViewController(vc) andSuccess(likeBlock) andFailure(showError) {

    displayLogin, with success (perform likeBlock on vc)
    andFailure (perform showError on vc)


}
```

I can't work out the syntax for this kind of passing around of blocks in Swift. How would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually probably easier than you think.

When you have a function such as `likePicture` that you declare, you can assign that function to a variable:

```
func likePicture(id:int) {
    println("Picture \(id) liked")
}

let like = likePicture

if loggedIn {
    // then call the stored function
    like(1)  // prints "Picture 1 liked"
} // etc
```

So unless you want to do something additional, such as manipulate the input before passing it into the function, there's no need to declare a block to call it (in Swift, these blocks are called closure expressions).

Since you can treat functions like any other value, this means you can do things like this:

```
func hatePicture(id:int) {
    println("Picture \(id) hated")
}

let action = someUserInput() ? likePicture : hatePicture
// later...
action(1)  // performs liking or hating of picture depending which was picked
```

All that's required is that the different functions that can be assigned to the variable all have the same type (i.e. signature, declaration etc), in this case they are both of type `(Int) -> Void` i.e. take a single integer argument and return nothing.

So to declare your function that receives a liking function as an argument, you would do something like:

```
func attemptLoginWithViewController(vc: WhateverVCType, #onSuccess: (Int)->Void, #onFailure: (Int)->Void) {
   // call onSuccess(id) or onFailure(id) depending
}

// and to call it:
attemptLoginWithViewController(vc, onSuccess: likePicture) { println("aargh kerbang") }
```

(note, instead of supplying a failure function, I use a trailing closure, but the point here is functions defined with `func` and functions defined using closure expressions are interchangeable)

Comment: Thanks. In my question I would need to pass that like(1) to the appDelegate's attemptLogin function (if they are not logged in). Then I need to perform this like(1) on the original view controller (if login is successful), or do something else if not successful. How would I pass this suff around?

Comment: I'm not at a computer with Swift installed at the moment, so beware a possible typo/syntax error in my code, but I think it's OK